# Using Views for Multilingual Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, multilingual

This is a subject that has been discussed multiple times and it always depens on the situation, but I like to share my idea.

Im building a new CMS that must support multilingual applications and can be installed behind existing applications.

The solutions I know and found are:

```
[Product]
id
price
name_en
name_de
name_fr

only getting the fields you need in your language.
```

or using mutliple tables like:

```
[product]
id
price

[languages]
id
tag

[product_translation]
product_id
language_id
name

 Joining the correct language
```

Both situations work and have its pro's and cons. Based on your choice you have to rewrite your query's.

my idea:

```
[product]
id
price
name

[product_translations]
product_id
language_id
name

[product_es_view]
id -- references the product table
price -- references the product table 
name -- references the translation table
```

Now the idea is that you create a view for every language, but the view is identical to the product table.

Why?
With this setup I can make non-multilingual sites, multilingual without editing the existing model/table. Now the only thing I have to do in my code is use another table and i get a translated version of my model (in php it could be done by adding a simple trait to your model). With SQL server and Mysql you can use updateable views which save the value's in the referenced tables.

I love to hear what you guys think of the idea, and most of all what the biggest cons are of using views for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second option where every entity is in its own table. If you use product_es_view then it may be easier but less clean code.

Adding new languages should usually not include adding new database tables. Adding new row to languages tables is better.